# Some Woocommerce customers not showing in customers section

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

Some Woocommerce customers are not showing in customers section but I can see them in the user section.
For example Customer ABC has 3 orders, I can see the user ABC in customers section but I can't see him in
woocommerce>customers.

There's no record of him, I've checked his role, he is customer by role.

Many others show fine, and the one's that show and those users that don't show have same roles that is ''customers''.

Can someone help please

Comment: Does the customer appear in the dashboard when the order status is changed to pending/processed/completed?

Comment: Hi Aliqua, Thank you for the response.
These were actually imported customers and orders from shopify.

Comment: It's a live site? -- Im only guessing but I dont think customers will come up until a purchase is made through woocommerce. You can possibly make a ticket on woocommerce/github to see if they can role out a future fix relating to imports?

Comment: Yes, it's live website. All the customers and orders data was imported. 70% of the imported users do show up in customers section as well but about 30% don't even though there is is no difference in the roles, they are all customers

Comment: Sorry Waize, its outside my scope. Goodluck finding an answer.

Comment: That's okay Aliqua. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem except none of my imported customers were showing. I noticed that in Woocommerce -> Status -> Scheduled Actions a bunch of tasks were created related to the import and left as *Pending*. The task was called *wc-admin_import_orders* and had an argument like `0 => 3333` (the second number was the order id). The tasks were also backdated by about 3 months. When I ran those tasks the users I had imported started showing in the Woocommerce -> customers section.

In my case I had about 2000 tasks to run and used WP-CLI [action-scheduler](https://actionscheduler.org/wp-cli/) command to run them. The command I used was `[root]# wp action-scheduler run --hooks='wc-admin_import_orders'`. You will need access to the terminal though. If that's not possible it can also be done by running them from the admin panel but it could take awhile if you have a lot of them.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I can manually fix it from time to time by running the command. However, I would prefer a solution for fixing it for real. Any idea?
My wordpress site is deployed as a Docker image. It might be related to this and the ports that are being used.